# How is this function even? $f(t)=(\pi-t)^2$, for $0\le t \le2\pi$

Tags: functions, fourier-series

How is the following function even?

$$f(t)=(\pi-t)^2, \quad 0\le t \le2\pi$$

Since $$f(-\pi)= \text{not defined} \ne 0 = f(\pi)$$

It is only even in the case that $t=0$

---

On the topic of Fourier Series now, lecturer claims that since the function is even, the $b_n$ coefficients will all vanish.

Comment: Who says that it's even?

Comment: What makes you think that it might be even? Are you working from some source that claims it is?

Comment: What is true is that this function extends to an even function with period $2\pi$ to the whole line.

Comment: @David, if this is coming from a discussion of Fourier series, then presumably the function, which is formally defined on the interval $[0,2\pi]$, is to be understood as a function on all of $\mathbb{R}$ with period $2\pi$, in which case it *is* an even function, as suggested in Kabo Murphy's comment.

Comment: @JMoravitz First define it on $[-\pi,0]$ and then extend from $[-\pi, \pi]$ to $\mathbb R$ by periodicity . This is considered quite 'natural' in the Theory of Fourier series.

Comment: @KaboMurphy what do you mean that it might be an even function to the whole line, if we assume that t is defined on the entire line then $f(\pi)=0\ne {4\pi}^2 =f(-\pi)$, I don't believe I understand what you mean.

Comment: You are thinking that there is only **one way** a function can be  extended from the given interval to the real line. You cannot define $f(t)$ to be $(t-\pi)^{2}$ for all $t$ to get an even extension. What I am saying is that **there exists** an even function on the line which is an extension of the given function. For this you only have to use the fact $f$ has the same value at $0$ and $2\pi$.  @David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is, of course, not even as a function $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ because of the issue you point out. However, it is common in Fourier analysis to use an abuse of notation that justify the manipulation. Perhaps the professor forgot to mention this (or, worse, just looked at the Fourier coefficients and said something without thinking too hard about what it meant).

The typical view in Fourier analysis is that a function $f:[0,2\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is really meant to be thought as a function that takes an *angle* as input and outputs a real number; so it's a function whose domain is a *circle*. Then, the quantities $\pi$ and $-\pi$ both refer to the same angle on a circle, so both would evaluate to $0$ under this function. Essentially, to evaluate the function at an angle, we first shift the angle into the interval $[0,2\pi)$ and then apply the function. The more elegant way to do this is to write $f$ as a function from $S^1$ (the unit circle) to $\mathbb R$, but it's often easier to work in terms of $[0,2\pi)$ in order to define a function, especially since different authors define the unit circle in different ways and since "take the angle from the interval $[0,2\pi)$ and square its difference from $\pi$" is hard to express naturally in terms of a circle. Geometrically, "even" then means that the function is the same evaluated at a counterclockwise rotation of $\theta$ and a clockwise rotation of $\theta$.

This is also sometimes expressed as saying that we are *really* studying functions with period $2\pi$ - that is function for which
$$f(x)=f(x+2\pi).$$
Then, given a definition of $f$ on the interval $[0,2\pi)$, we can figure out a function $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by using the above property. Applying this to the definition you were given does indeed yield an even function.